# How to pick the previous and next record from a datasource using linq when the datasource is ordered by name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have come across a situation where I need to show the previous and next record of a matching record , suppose I have a data source for products and the products are sorted by name . Now after retrieving the product by id I also want to retrieve the very next and previous product but in alphabetic order .
How can I achieve this using LINQ ?

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list in alphabetic order, find the index of your entry and look for the entries with index+/-1.

```
list = list.OrderBy( x => x.name ).ToList();
list.IndexOf( entry );
var a = list[entry-1];
var b = list[entry+1];
```

Comment: This isn't LINQ and could be more efficient but would work.

Comment: yes, there are of course faster approaches. still, ORDERBY, TOLIST and INDEXOF are Linq commands

Comment: the record set I am dealing with may contain tens of thousands of data , so making it ToList() isn't a good option

Comment: a few thousand items should not matter, but if performance is an issue, please have a look at the min/max solution which runs in O(2n). Without Linq, a single traverse can be performed in O(1n)

Answer (score 0):

more efficient way without sorting the list:

```
var a = list.Where( x => x.name < entry ).Max( x => x.name );
var b = list.Where( x => x.name > entry ).Min( x => x.name );
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient non-LINQ answer, assuming the sequence is pre-sorted.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Beside<T>(
         this IEnumerable<T> source,
         T target,
         IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default)
{
    comparer ??= EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(target);

    T previous = default;
    bool found = false;
    foreach(T item in source)
    {
        if (found)
        {
            yield return item;
            break;
        }
        
        if (comparer.Equals(item, target))
        {
            found = true;
            yield return previous;
        }
        else
        {
            previous = item;
        }
    }
}
```